# Cell bottom line truncate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I use basic style for cell in Storyboard and I don't understand why I see truncating bottom line for images:

[image]

How this can be fixed? I want bottom grey line will be all the cells bottom long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for remove:

```
 self.yourTable.separatorStyle = .none
```

for stretch out:

```
 cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

or

```
 self.yourTable.separatorInset = .zero
```